# Exclude ranges across worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

How can I exclude ranges across worksheets? I am getting *Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed*.

```
Dim rExclude(1) As Range, idx As Integer, rRange As Range
Set rExclude(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table").ListColumns("Column").DataBodyRange
Set rExclude(1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table").ListColumns("Column").DataBodyRange
For idx = 0 To 1
    For Each rRange In rExclude(idx)
        If Not Intersect(Target, rRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Next rRange
Next idx
```

Comment: You can't `Intersect` ranges on different worksheets. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not trying to intersect ranges across worksheets; rather, to exclude ranges from code in a Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick sub.

Comment: But `Intersect(Target, rRange)` attempts to do *exactly* that if `Target` and `rRange` are not on the same sheet. You have to check if the parent worksheet is the same before attempting to `Intersect`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Application.Intersect` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect):

> If one or more ranges from a different worksheet are specified, an error is returned.

You can't call `Intersect` on ranges with different parent worksheets, so test if the parent is the same:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
    ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 

    '...

    For Each rRange In rExclude(idx)
        If rRange.Parent Is Sh Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, rRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, if I wanted to _restrict_ the sub to the stated ranges, why would changing `If Not Intersect` to `If Intersect` exit the sub?

Comment: Probably because at some iteration of the loop(s), the `Intersect`ion of `Target` and `rRange` is in fact `Nothing`. I don't think the logic of using `Exit Sub` would work if you want to loop until you get to the `Intersect` of the stated range and `Target`.